# iOS 16, Xcode 14 - Widget background images are not displayed

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, ios16, xcode14

I have been testing widgets in my app ever since I downloaded Xcode 14. But I see a grey box instead of background images. Here is the code snippet.

```
Image("LargeBackgroundImage")
                .resizable()
                .clipped()
                .scaledToFill()
                .overlay(Color.black.opacity(0.55))
                .accessibilityHidden(true)
```

And this is the result.

[image: Screenshot of iOS 16 simulator with rectangular lock screen widget]

It would be helpful if anyone can share the solution.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the issue as well. It has something to do with the size of the image file.

I can't find any documentation on the size limits, so I don't know what they are.

But the image file itself has a size limit. So even if you resize it in code, it won't matter.

Update: PNG with size 145x145 seems to do the trick.